# ArrayList how to add Integer attributes - Logic issue

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class called `Animal` and it has the following fields;

```
String ani_Name;
int animal_maintainance_cost;
```

I have a class called `Maintenance`. and:

1. It has a method to calculate the total animal maintenance Cost of an Animal in the Zoo.
2. It has a method to calculate the animal maintenance cost of all animals in the zoo.

The code I tried:

```
private Map <Integer,Animal> animal = new HashMap<Integer,Animal>();

// Here, `Integer` is the `animalID `and `Animal `is an object of the class `Animal`
//Then i generated getters and setters, and using the setter method i will be adding all the animals in the Zoo.
```

#### 1

```
public int returnAllAnimalMaintenanceCost(Integer animalID){
  int animalMaintenaceCostForGivenAnimalID = ???? // How do i calculate this using `Map <Integer,Animal>`
return animalMaintenaceCostForGivenAnimalID;

}
```

#### 2

```
public int returnAllAnimalMaintenanceCost() {
   return ??
}
```

Can someone please help me to calculate the total cost of maintenance of all the animals in the Zoo.

Comment: Iterate over your ArrayList and call some method to get the maintenance cost of that animal and sum them.

Comment: I assumed he made a mistake posting the code over. It's probably intended to be `ArrayList<Animal>()`

Comment: is this really an interesting question?

Comment: Please clarify your question with what is already there and which part of code is to be written by you (where you're facing the problem). ArrayList is a "list", you probably need a map.

Comment: Yes, i need a Map, and i will edit my post shortly

Comment: How can animalId match to an Animal ?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `Integer` as well

Comment: How do you store how many animals there are of each different type?

Comment: Are IDs unique to each animal instance or each animal type?

Answer (score 1):

At first I was thinking "you need a HashMap" then I thought that you probably don't need a HashMap. Now I realize that yes, you probably want a HashMap to store the number of animals of each type.

I think that the concept of mapping an `animalId` to an animal is a little strange, as I think the name of each animal already is unique, why the need of an Id?

I believe this could work for you:
I assume below that the animal map is used to map an Animal to a count (how many of each animal type there are).

```
private Map<Animal, Integer> animal = new HashMap<Animal, Integer>();

public int returnAllAnimalMaintenanceCost() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Entry<Animal, Integer> ee : animal.entrySet()) {
        sum += ee.getValue() * ee.getKey().getMaintenanceCost();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

To find the maintenance cost for a specific animal, you could input the name of the animal instead, loop through your animal.keySet(), find the specific animal that you are looking for, return the maintenance cost in your Animal class multiplied by the number of animals existing of that type.

Comment: Thank you, but how do i do this to get the cost of a particular Animal. I will be passing its ID

Comment: How do you get an Animal object from the ID? I don't see you mentioning the ID much in your question.

Comment: Using the Setter method of the `private Map<Animal, Integer> animal = new HashMap<Animal, Integer>();` (as shown in your post) i will set Animal Ids and Animals to it (most probably in the constructor)

Comment: OK, then how do you store how many animals there are of each different type?

Comment: From the constructor i will be setting values (hardcode) for Animal and It's ID. and then using the method signature `public int returnAllAnimalMaintenanceCost(Integer animalID)` i will be passing an ID and trying to retrieve the total maintenance cost of a particular animal

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get a specific animal's id:

```
public int returnAnimalMaintenanceCost(int animalID) {
    return animal.get(animalID).getCost();
}
```

You might consider renaming your map to `aminals`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Constants
{
      public static int ANIMAL_ID = 0;
      public Map <Integer,Animal> animal = new HashMap<Integer,Animal>();
}
```

Animal class

```
public class Animal
{
      public int id;
      String ani_Name;
      int animal_maintainance_cost;
      public Animal()
      {
            id = ++Constants.Animal_ID;
            constants.put( id, this );
      }
}
```

Maintenance class

```
public class Maintenance
{
     public int totalAnimalMaintenanceCostOfAnAnimal(Integer animalID)
     {
         return (Constants.get( animalID )).animal_maintainance_cost;
     }

     public int returnAllAnimalMaintenanceCost() 
     {
         int sum = 0;
          for ( int i = 1; i <= Constants.ANIMAL_ID; i++) 
          {
                sum = sum + (Constants.get( i)).animal_maintainance_cost;
          }
          return sum;
     }
}
```

Comment: I would loop through the entry set of the map instead of this for loop ´for ( int i = 1; i <= Constants.ANIMAL_ID; i++)`.

Comment: if you consider performance, both are one and the same, it does not really matter whether you loop through map or entry set. Both will have a order of N... I just gave the complete solution to your problem. That's it. No part code.

Comment: With your for-loop, you depend on this code: `id = ++Constants.Animal_ID; constants.put( id, this );` What if the Constants.Animal_ID got changed to something else? I don't consider performance - I know our solutions are equal there. I consider code independence.

Comment: I also should add that besides your for-loop, and the fact that there is no `Constants.get`-method (I assume you mean `Constants.animal.get`), I like your solution.

Comment: You need to set the id for each animal, it should be done at the constructor level and it has to be unique or else it does not serve your purpose. So using constants ensure you that it will always be unique, and hash map is populated with unique ID's and again this is just one of the way to achieve unique IDs

Comment: And also it gives me easy access so that I can get maintenance cost of each animal easily... SO no more fundo0 logic there